# How to recursively go through all text files in a directory to fetch the desired line, and write these lines to same text file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a directory which has text files (HTML pages). I wish to use SED to go through these text files, find the specific line, and write the line to a single text file.

So for example I have `HTMLS` as my directory with sample text files `1,2,3,4` and these are all HTML pages. I think I could use SED *search for a line command* (correct me if I'm wrong) -

```
sed -n 'line number' 1.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Considering the `> outputfile.txt` part works, how do I make this command go through all the text files, and save all outputs to `outputfile.txt` ? If my implementation seems off please let me know which might be a better way. Thanks!!

Comment: In other words, you want to fetch the 5th line (for example) of every `*.txt` file in your directory, right? Did you try `sed -n '5p' ?.txt > outputfile.txt`?

Comment: `grep "line number" -r .` will search recursively from `.`

Comment: @PerlDuck to output the 5th line of each of multiple files, you will need the `-s` (`--separate`) flag as well I think